# Resolving conflict between openvpn subnet domain and local subnet domain

Tags: openvpn, route, subnets

I connect to my employer's network via an openvpn setup. That gets me into a `192.168.22.0/22` subnet, with a gateway into the real network I need (inside my employer's internal net) at `192.168.20.0/22`. Ordinarily this just works and I never have to think about it.

Well here I am at a coffee shop whose wifi gives out `192.168.20.0/24` addresses. I thus end up with a route conflict:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.20.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.20.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.20.0    192.168.22.49   255.255.252.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.22.49   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
```

I'm pretty much out of luck, right? I can get to the Internet (of course, or I couldn't be typing this), and if I drop that route through `0.0.0.0` then I can get to the VPN, but I can't do both at the same time. I'm not much of a network person so I'm just wondering whether there's a solution to this, either via openvpn client config or whatever.

Comment: Have you checked if OpenVPN's `--redirect-private` helps?

Comment: @derobert no; I'll read up on it. I'm home from the coffee shop now so I won't get to try it until next week :)  Thanks!!